# Caption of figure in list of figures in Lyx

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, captions

my question is often asked and as often answered for regular Latex, but I would like to know, if there is a simple way in Lyx to make a custom entry for a caption in the list of figures, just like it's done in regular Latex with

`\caption[shown in list of figures]{complete caption under the figure}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a new float, write the caption, and then, right-click over the caption, and select <kbd>Insert Short Title</kbd> in the menu

[image: menu]

This make a `opt` box inside the caption where you can write the text  shown in the list of figures. The results must be:

[image: result]

With <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>View source</kbd> you can see that the generated LaTeX code will be:

```
\caption[shown in list of figures]{complete caption under the figure}
```

Comment: Just as a note, I believe that LyX has improved things in later versions (I believe as of 2.1.0) so that the "opt" box now says "Short Title".